# Flashed Intel Braswell Chromebook but still getting OS verification off screen

Tags: chrome-book

I've flashed my Intel Braswell Chromebook with the `RW_LEGACY` flash,  and installed Gallium. But every time I restart I get the `OS verification off` screen.

I can bypass this with `ctrl + l`. But since I flashed it, why do I still have to do this?

Answer (score 0):

That's because one needs to flash either UEFI Full ROM or BOOT_STUB

More info here: https://wiki.galliumos.org/Firmware

Answer (score 0):

Or remove the bitmaps to just display `developer mode warning` and set the boot options to boot Chrome OS or legacy boot slot after 2 seconds instead of 30.

https://mrchromebox.tech/#fwscript

Comment: It says `Requires firmware write-protect disabled`. Meaning I would have to physically open and remove the screw to be able to do this right?

Comment: Correct, but that's also reguired for UEFI boot stub or full rom, exect that this allows you to still boot Chrome OS.